# apache + hhvm fastcgi

Tags: php, apache, url, hhvm

i'm trying to migrate my project from apache2.2 to apache2 + hhvm with apache as reverse proxy.

Before migration i had this apache configuration ( to make pretty urls ):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(server-status)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

so portal urls were like: examples.com/post/post-title-as-slug

Now i have this configuration for apache:

```
<IfModule mod_fastcgi.c>
<FilesMatch \.php$>
    SetHandler hhvm-php-extension
</FilesMatch>

<FilesMatch \.hh$>
    SetHandler hhvm-hack-extension
</FilesMatch>

Alias /ec /ec
Action hhvm-php-extension /ec virtual
Action hhvm-hack-extension /ec virtual

FastCgiExternalServer /ec -host 127.0.0.1:9000 -pass-header Authorization -idle-timeout 300

</IfModule>
```

And this hhvm config ( server.ini ):

```
hhvm.server.port = 9000
hhvm.server.type = fastcgi
hhvm.server.default_document = index.php
hhvm.log.use_log_file = true
hhvm.log.file = /var/log/hhvm/error.log
hhvm.repo.central.path = /var/run/hhvm/hhvm.hhbc
hhvm.server.source_root = /w3/dr/
```

This config works only if i set urls like: examples.com/index.php/post/post-title-as-slug but if url is like: examples.com/post/post-title-as-slug i receive a 404 http error.

I want to remove index.php from url.

Anyone knows a solution ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As per [Facebook HHVM Issue #3472](https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/issues/3472) you have to set **`hhvm.server.fix_path_info = true`** in the **hhvm config** if you are using any **mod_rewrite** rule.